# DirectShow: Stream positions after mixing in VMR9

Tags: directshow

I use two pins for mixing in VMR9.  `IVMRMixerControl9` gives us two methods for its control: `SetOutputRect()` and `GetOutputRect()`. But those methods work with normalized values in composition space.

Is there any way to know the real position of each stream after mixing?

Comment: You can do simple math to get approximate "real position". I used quotes because there is no such thing in first place. VMR does not have to compose a mixed frame - in traditional understanding - instead it positions the frames in 3D space following your requests and has it rendered by 3D hardware. Hence, pixel accurate positions don't have to be available.